# AppleScript: alias reference is not changing after renaming a folder

Tags: macos, applescript, alias

I'm new to AppleScript and after doing:

```
set folder_name to "New_Folder"
tell application "Finder" to make new folder at desktop
set my_folder to result as alias
tell application "Finder" to set the name of my_folder to folder_name
get my_folder
```

I get: alias "/Users/frank/Desktop/untitled folder"

I thought alias was dynamic, why my_folder reference is not changing after renaming the folder? 
i.e. alias "/Users/frank/Desktop/New_Folder"
How can I accomplish that?

Comment: I am getting the same issue on Mac OS High Sierra 10.13.6 (17G65)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure why you're not getting the correct information. Running your code on my system (macOS High Sierra) returns the correct alias to the renamed folder.

[image]

This code should return the proper value for the alias value you are looking for

```
set folder_name to "New_Folder"
tell application "Finder" to set my_folder to ¬
    (make new folder at desktop with properties {name:folder_name}) as alias
return my_folder
```